# How to make a call with a fake identifier?

Tags: java, android, call

I wish to make a call to the person who receives it appears another number to the current, only now I make the call, I need to pass as a parameter a name or number that appears to the person receiving the call

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1645"));
intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_CALL);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This intent is an action with the correct number to call, so changing a number before calling is not good and after it is too late. Maybe you should think harder and improve your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so long I add the solution to the question.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:600"));
        intent.putExtra("account", 0);
        startActivity(intent);
```

It should be noted that the device handled several telephone bills and therefore the code did not work

Answer (score 0):

Thats not even to do with the Android OS.
It has to do with GSM settings, and it chiped in the SIM card.